# Tell cloud to deploy XML with appropriate MIMEType

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I have an RSS feed that I'm putting in the Cloud. Unfortunately, the Cloud is a disaster and can't even get the MIME-type right by default.

It gives me (note I’ve since manually changed the MIME-type so this is different):

```
URLRead["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/index/rss_feed.xml", "Headers"]~Lookup~"content-type"

"application/octet-stream"
```

Here's what it should have given me:

```
URLRead["https://paclets.github.io/PacletServer/index/rss_feed.xml", "Headers"]~Lookup~"content-type"

"application/xml"
```

Now, in my `CopyFile` call I can specify the `"MIMType"` explicitly ([per this kludge](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/500336)). I can even do this semi-automatically via:

```
CopyFile[file, dest, 
 "MIMEType"->
  ImportExport`GetMIMEType[
   ToUpperCase@StringTrim[FileExtension[file], "."]
   ][[1]]
 ]
```

It'd be much nicer though if in the intervening two years something had come up to allow me to tell Mathematica what MIME-type to use for which extensions without my having to supply this manually.

Is there such a thing?

Comment: Quick thought, have you tried deploying HTTPResponse with manually crafted headers/content? (sorry if I missed the point and that is not suitable)

Comment: @Kuba I can't say I entirely know what you're trying to get at, although I think I do. My use case for this is as the RSS feed for a static website, so it'd be best to be able to serve the resources statically (and I have a workaround for my specific case). On the other hand, if I weren't just copying files that would be an entirely reasonable approach. Certainly would allow for more fine-grained control over what happens.

Comment: What version are you using? I get this in 11.3: `In[12]:= URLRead[
  "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/b3m2a1/tutorial/index/rss_\
feed.xml", "Headers"]~Lookup~"content-type"

Out[12]= "APPLICATION/XML"`

Comment: @GenericAccountName that’s because I’ve since patched the MIME-type to be correct